# Is it possible to create a smart tv application that manipulates with the TV input

Tags: android-tv, apple-tv, smart-tv

I'm new at smart-tv development and wonder if it's possible to:

1. Create an app as a layer, and still display the user TV channel?
2. Manipulate the sound or the video channels?

example:
is it possible to create an app that displays my tv channel only that the sound is turned into Helium sound?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried [developing a TV Input Service](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/tvinput.html)? This TV input service works with the Android system TV app. This app ultimately controls and presents channel content on the TV.